# Problems with Magento prices after included tax class to product

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I used an option to add 21% tax to all products and for some reason some prices now came up as ± 1 cent, e.g.:

http://vinylshop.lt/dj-3/patefonai-priedai/dj-patefonu-adatos/ortofon-concorde-pro-s-adata.html

http://vinylshop.lt/dj-3/patefonai-priedai/dj-patefonu-adatos/stanton-trackmaster-v3-mp4-2-adatos.html

In admin - showing OK, but in frontend - NOT.

Have you ever encountered an issue like this? How can this be fixed? 
My Magento version 1.6.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento tax rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529580/magento-tax-rounding-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the famous magento rounding bug:

go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php`

change method round to 4 digits:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
return round($price, 4);
}
```

Best practice would of course be not to hack the core file. At least copy file to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php or do a rewrite. Well good is neither of the actions, but there might be no other way....

have fun!