# PHP rounding issue

Tags: php, magento

We have a problem on our Google Shopping feed which seems to be a rounding issue. THis has caused Google to suspend our feed and the combined might of myself and 2 development agencies we use can not seem to fix it.

The script does the following;

Get the price (or special price if on special) of the product;

```
  if ($product->getSpecialPrice() &&
     ($product->getSpecialPrice() < $product->getPrice()))
  {
       $tempPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
  } 
  else 
  {
       $tempPrice = $product->getPrice();
  }
```

Add the VAT by multiplying by 1.2

```
  $_priceIncludingTax = $tempPrice * 1.2;
```

Using the PHP round() function to round the price to the nearest 2 decimal places (this should do half up and less down by default, i.e 1.5 = 2 and 1.4 = 1 (according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)))

```
  $_priceIncludingTax = round($_priceIncludingTax, 2);
```

This should work for all our products for example the 3 examples below;

SKU | Price in website backend | X 1.2  | rounded | Whats actually in feed

*DL229 |    589.86 |    707.832 | 707.83 |  707.84*

SKU | Price in website backend | X 1.2  | rounded | Whats actually in feed

*CB020 |    9.06 |  10.872 |    10.87 | 10.88*

SKU | Price in website backend | X 1.2  | rounded | Whats actually in feed

*DM056 |    16.93 | 20.316 |    20.32 | 20.31*

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172442/problems-with-magento-prices-after-included-tax-class-to-product - this may be the issue you're having

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution as it changes the website rather than the values generated on the feed. However I have tried it and it has bought the website prices in line with the (unexpected) values on the feed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento tax rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529580/magento-tax-rounding-issue)

Comment: @Victor S. You are probably correct. I did ask my question 2 years previous to the linked question but I am not sure on stackoverflow duplication etiquette.