# Magento 1.9.1 rounding issue...again/still

Tags: magento, rounding, magento-1.9

The price should be 50,90 but is 50,91 - i thought the problem is solved yet. But obviously it does not work. Any hints to fix this?

base_subtotal **49,5800**

base_tax_amount **8,13**

shipping_amount **4,12**

shipping_tax_amount **0,79**

subtotal_incl_tax **59,00**

total_due **50,91**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento tax rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529580/magento-tax-rounding-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calculating the VAT (Steuern) from the total.

For starters, shipping_amount + shipping_tax_amount doesn't add up: 4,12 + 0,79 = 4,91.

I think you made the classic mistake using floats to divide, add and subtract, then round the numbers for printing them but still using the unrounded numbers in other paths.

I don't know how you got 0.79 as shipping_tax_amount; 4.90 divided by 1.19 is 4.117647...; rounded that gives a 4.12. Unless you truncated 4.1176747.. to 4.11, then subtract that from 4.90 => 0.79.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

- Use integer calculation, by treating all amounts as cents
- Use rounding at **every multiplication or division**

The two solutions are essentially the same, since an integer is always implicitly rounded. Also, when calculating the VAT portion of an amount, don't use a division directly, but subtract from the total:

```
shipping = 4.90;
shipping_without_vat = round(shipping / 1.19, 2);
shipping_vat = shipping - shipping_without_vat;
```

Then use shipping_without_vat and shipping_vat for the remainder of the calculations.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am talking about standard core magento 1.9.1. I am not doing a thing with the calculations! Putting the "round to four digits" classic move in place it works - but i thought this wouldnt be necessary since 1.8

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that you weren't coding yourself. The most obvious reply would then have been 'File a bugreport with Magento' :) Apparently they are making the same classical mistakes I wrote down...